# How to Edit or Customize the WooCommerce add order button on admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I already googled this but I found nothing, so Im asking here can anyone help how to edit the "Add order" button to "Add Transactions"..

[image: Button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is untested but it should work ;)

Double check the spelling of "Add order", the capitalization has to be exactly the same to make it work.

```
function translate_add_order_backend( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if( is_admin() ) {

      switch ( $translated_text ) {
          case 'Add order' :
              $translated_text = 'Add Transactions';
              break;
      }

    }

    return $translated_text;

}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_add_order_backend', 20, 3 );
```

The code can be pasted into your theme functions.php file.

Comment: ok let me check this one...I will update you later sir if this fails...thank you..

Comment: yes sir actually it works...thank you so much...I'm a student and this is my thesis project...you save my day..

Comment: ammm sir @FrancescoCarlucci I still have a question regarding this post...how to edit or Customize also the "Order" label before the "Add Order" buttons...check also my post picture...thank you.,